# How to sum count query inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php 
    foreach($idd as $ids)
    {
        $sql5 = "select count(DISTINCT product_name) as total from stock where type = '".$ids."'";
        $result5 = mysqli_query($con,$sql5);
        $row5 = mysqli_fetch_row($result5);
    }
    $total5 = $row5[0];
?>
```

In this code I have used explode function for `$idd` and run query inside foreach loop and want to sum of multiple query inside foreach loop and Now, My query look like:

```
select count(DISTINCT product_name) as total from stock where type = 'Green Tea'select count(DISTINCT product_name) as total from stock where type = 'Herbal Tea'
```

But I want like this

```
select (select count(DISTINCT product_name) as total from inventory_add_in_stock where type = 'Green Tea')+(select count(DISTINCT product_name) as total from inventory_add_in_stock where type = 'Herbal Tea') as total
```

So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch values inside `foreach()` and sum them. Do like below:-

```
<?php

    $total_count = 0; // a varible define to get total count in last
    foreach($idd as $ids)
    {
        $sql5 = "select count(DISTINCT product_name) as total from stock where type = '".$ids."'";
        $result5 = mysqli_query($con,$sql5) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        $row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5);
        $total_count += $row5['total']; // add counts to variable
    }
    echo $total_count; // print final count
?>
```

Your code is wide open for `SQL INJECTION`. try to use `prepared statements`

[mysqli_prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

***Note:-*** Try to do it without loop

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102345